# How to access values from error responses

Tags: swift, swift5, xcode12

Hi I am getting an error from the api response bases on the error code I have to show the error popup.

```
 Error Domain=com.ca.mailina.targetAPI:ErrorDomain Code=1854 "The data 
couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." UserInfo= 
{mailinaInfoHeaderInfoKey=<CFBasicHash 0x600000bff000 [0x7fff8004b340]>{type = 
immutable dict, count = 8,
entries =>
0 : Pragma = no-cache
1 : x-up-err = 0001854
2 : Content-Type = <CFString 0x6000011c63a0 [0x7fff8004b340]>{contents = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"}
3 : x-mail-err = 100
4 : x-uxp-err = 30102
6 : Date = <CFString 0x6000011c6370 [0xgghyd654fx40]>{contents = "Tue, 17 Aug 2021 10:37:19 GMT"}
10 : Content-Length = 907
11 : Cache-Control = no-store
}, NSLocalizedDescription=The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format., status-code=401}
```

I have to check the condition based on **4 : x-uxp-err = 30102** which is on the fourth position of error response now the problem is I am not able to access the 4th passion of response, guide me to get the solution, example

```
  if x-uxp-err == 30102 {
    print("open popup 1")
  } else {
    print("open popup 2")
  }
```

Comment: You have a `Error` or NSError property, right? Check its `userInfo["MASResponseInfoHeaderInfoKey"]`, I guess `let headerInfoKeys = (error as NSError).userInfo["MASResponseInfoHeaderInfoKey"] as? [String: Any]; let xUxpErr = headerInfoKeys["x-uxp-err"]`, and it might be a String, to trasnform it into `Int` if needed.

Comment: @Larme no I don't have the Error property

Comment: How did you print that?

Comment: from Error parameter while calling api

Comment: Sorry, I meant error variable (or parameter variable as you have), not property.

Comment: when I am calling the API we I have response, error so the above output is from error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236084/discussion-between-larme-and-sanjay-mishra).